# rt2870.o/rt2870.ko usb wireless adupter installation issue

Tags: linux, wifi, driver, parrot

i am using parrot Linux the latest version . i want to install/use a nano adapter (802.11n) USB

i tried several ways but i failed 
[tried 1](http://linuxforums.org.uk/index.php?topic=852.msg4472;PHPSESSID=2q077au4utdpfigc2t7hgo1dg5#msg4472)

after trying this i found no other way to ask for help 
the following error i am getting while using **make && make install**

```
└──╼ #sudo make && make install
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ano/Downloads/linux/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ano/Downloads/linux/tools'
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.1.8-parrot-686-pae/build SUBDIRS=/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.1.8-parrot-686-pae'
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c: In function ‘announce_802_3_packet’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.c:331:16: warning: unused variable ‘pAd’ [-Wunused-variable]
  RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd = (RTMP_ADAPTER *)pAdSrc;
                ^
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c: In function ‘PeerBeacon’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:2180:12: warning: passing argument 8 of ‘StaAddMacTableEntry’ from incompatible pointer type
            ie_list,
            ^
In file included from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sync.c:28:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rtmp.h:7892:9: note: expected ‘struct IE_LISTS *’ but argument is of type ‘struct BCN_IE_LIST *’
 BOOLEAN StaAddMacTableEntry(
         ^
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c: In function ‘STAHandleRxDataFrame’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:523:33: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘MacTableLookup’ from incompatible pointer type
    pEntry = MacTableLookup(pAd, &pHeader->Addr2);
                                 ^
In file included from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rt_config.h:59:0,
                 from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:28:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rtmp.h:8429:18: note: expected ‘UCHAR *’ but argument is of type ‘UCHAR (*)[6]’
 MAC_TABLE_ENTRY *MacTableLookup(RTMP_ADAPTER *pAd, UCHAR *pAddr);
                  ^
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlRF’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5306:7: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘LONG’ [-Wformat=]
       sprintf(msg+strlen(msg), "BANK%d_R%02d:%02X  ", bank_Id, rfId, rfValue);
       ^
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5359:27: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RtmpDrvAllRFPrint’ from incompatible pointer type
   RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(NULL, msg, strlen(msg));
                           ^
In file included from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rt_config.h:64:0,
                 from /home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:28:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/include/rt_os_util.h:668:6: note: expected ‘UINT32 *’ but argument is of type ‘PSTRING’
 VOID RtmpDrvAllRFPrint(
      ^
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5209:22: warning: unused variable ‘rf_bank’ [-Wunused-variable]
  UCHAR    regRF = 0, rf_bank = 0;
                      ^
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5766:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                     ^
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:5766:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
             snprintf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                                               ^
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_ioctl_siwgenie’:
/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7610:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
     eid_ptr = pAd->StaCfg.pWpaAssocIe;
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1384: recipe for target '_module_/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ano/Downloads/linux/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.1.8-parrot-686-pae'
Makefile:394: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

can one please check and help me on it ....

Answer (score 1):

I got that error, too, on a fresh Debian installation, despite being able to make that driver flawlessly a few times before.

Some problems were gone when I edited the *os/linux/config.mk* file as per the README file included in the driver folder, but then, new ones occured, considering something about the DATE and TIME functions.

I found that the solution is to install package [firmware-ralink](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-ralink) that also contains drivers for your USB Wireless dongle.

On my Debian Jessie installation, it said that *firmware-ralink* package is now included in the [firmware-non-free](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/kernel/firmware-linux-nonfree) package.